Error running Azure Function locally on Mac - Configuration is missing the 'HostEndpoint'
I'm trying to run a basic C# Azure Function with Time Trigger locally on a Mac within vsCode.
I have installed .Net 8 SDK, and and Azure Function Core Tools.
When I run the basic function (just the code from the New Function template from within vsCode) I get this error in the terminal.
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Configuration is missing the 'HostEndpoint' information. Please ensure an entry with the key 'Functions:Worker:HostEndpoint' is present in your configuration.
I expect this means I'm missing some basic local configuration, but I can't seem to find any references to this particular parameter. Does anyone know what I need to set?
Edit:
Adding the function code to the post...
Program.cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
.ConfigureServices(services => {
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
})
.Build();

host.Run();

TimeTrigger1.cs:
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class TimerTrigger1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public TimerTrigger1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TimerTrigger1>();
        }

        [Function("TimerTrigger1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            
            if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
            }
        }
    }
}

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}


Provide your function code and local.settings.json.

@PravallikaKV I've added to the post - thanks

Can you also share your .csproj?

Delete bin folder, rebuild the project and run the function again

if you are running through VS Code Run Button, it wouldn't work. You need to run the following command from the VS Code Terminal
func host start

If you are using 'Isolated Worker' model instead of 'In Process' model this should work:
func start func host --dotnet-isolated

